# Using exactly same configuration but still get “Configurations cannot be different” error in Realm Java SDK

Tags: java, android, mongodb, realm, mongodb-atlas

I'm using Realm Android Java SDK with Sync feature. I'm getting `Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file` error, although I'm using code in both the activities. These are the codes I'm using to get Realm Instance on `MainActivity`:

```java
App app = new App(new AppConfiguration.Builder("application-0").build());
SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(app.currentUser()).build();
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

And using the exact same code on another activity `CustomerActivity`:

```java
App app = new App(new AppConfiguration.Builder("application-0").build());
SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(app.currentUser()).build();
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Still getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file. 
 Cached configuration: 
  realmDirectory: /data/user/0/com.in/files/mongodb-realm/application-0/65566a52ab8ce3e71ebdcf22
  realmFileName : default.realm
  canonicalPath: /data/user/0/com.in/files/mongodb-realm/application-0/65566a52ab8ce3e71ebdcf22/default.realm
  key: [length: 0]
  schemaVersion: 0
  migration: null
  deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
  durability: FULL
  schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@fcf6dfb
  readOnly: false
  compactOnLaunch: null
  maxNumberOfActiveVersions: 9223372036854775807
  serverUrl: wss://realm.mongodb.com/
  user: io.realm.mongodb.User@95acac88
  errorHandler: io.realm.mongodb.AppConfiguration$Builder$1@fcda401
  initialSubscriptions: null
  deleteRealmOnLogout: false
  syncClientValidateSsl: true
  serverCertificateAssetName: null
  serverCertificateFilePath: null
  waitForInitialData: false
  initialDataTimeoutMillis: 9223372036854775807
  sessionStopPolicy: AFTER_CHANGES_UPLOADED
  syncUrlPrefix: /api/client/v2.0/app/application-0-vaocb/realm-sync
  partitionValue: null
    
 New configuration: 
  realmDirectory: /data/user/0/com.in/files/mongodb-realm/application-0/65566a52ab8ce3e71ebdcf22
  realmFileName : default.realm
  canonicalPath: /data/user/0/com.in/files/mongodb-realm/application-0/65566a52ab8ce3e71ebdcf22/default.realm
  key: [length: 0]
  schemaVersion: 0
  migration: null
  deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: false
  durability: FULL
  schemaMediator: io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator@fcf6dfb
  readOnly: false
  compactOnLaunch: null
  maxNumberOfActiveVersions: 9223372036854775807
  serverUrl: wss://realm.mongodb.com/
  user: io.realm.mongodb.User@e4199dbc
  errorHandler: io.realm.mongodb.AppConfiguration$Builder$1@7bbf883
  initialSubscriptions: null
  deleteRealmOnLogout: false
  syncClientValidateSsl: true
  serverCertificateAssetName: null
  serverCertificateFilePath: null
  waitForInitialData: false
  initialDataTimeoutMillis: 9223372036854775807
  sessionStopPolicy: AFTER_CHANGES_UPLOADED
  syncUrlPrefix: /api/client/v2.0/app/application-0-vaocb/realm-sync
  partitionValue: null
```

Here is the diffchecker screenshot:
[image]